# How do I remove a portion of a vector layer line string?

Tags: gps-track-editor

This is probably basic but I am a complete newbie. I searched for editing layers but am having difficulty understanding it. Here's what I have and understand so far.

I imported a KML file as a vector line. I understand I can't edit the KML import directly. I need to first save it as an ESRI shapefile. I have done that. I also toggled edit mode for the new layer and turned on the Vertex tool, which I think (not sure) is the same as the Node tool I've seen descried elsewhere - at least the icon looks the same. But then I am completely lost.

In the graphic, the magenta line is the complete track. The yellow box represents the portion I am trying to keep. I would like to delete the rest. I'm hoping this does not require a point-at-a-time deletion. For example, the segment in the yellow box from the loop on the top left to the "racetrack" at the middle right is about 9 miles. That would be a lot of points!

[image: Sample for illustration]

Comment: It sounds like you are using QGIS, but could you confirm which software you are working with. This will help others to answer your question. If you are using QGIS, try the tool 'Extract/ clip by extent from the processing toolbox.

Comment: Sorry, yes QGIS 3.12 Windows. Vector | Research Tools | Extract Layer Extent gave me nothing at all.

Comment: Ah. Found a simple solution. A stand-alone track editor. Allowed me to break the track into segments and save the segments I want separately. Then I just import them into. QGIS where I can use them for something the editor doesn't do.

Comment: For the record, my suggestion was 'Extract/ clip by extent'. 'Extract layer extent' is completely unrelated! But good you found something that worked for you anyway...

Comment: I do appreciate the help. I can see it's a good program but I think QGIS is far more complex in some areas than what I need. I looked at QGIS for it's ability ability to import a georeferenced pdf file and overlay a track on it. It does that very easily but the tracks I use need to be broken up to be useful and that part was easier done in another program.